# Reading Motor Datasheet

Tags: motors, machine-design

I'm doing my first machine design for a project and I have a Honda GX160 combustion motor which has the following specs for power and speed:
[image]

I'd like to use 0.24 HP at 2000 rpm. Is this possible? Or I can just get 2000 rpm at 2.1 HP as the NET POWER curve shows?

I'm using this motor because it's the only one I have available for this project.

(It would also work for me at 1300 rpm if it has at least 0.24 HP, but I don't think its recommended)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart shows the maximum power with the throttle wide open.

You can run at lower powers simply by having the throttle partly closed.

If you want to use a low power output like 0.24HP, you will probably need some sort of automatic control system to keep the RPM down to 2000. A simple throttle lever with manual adjustment might be too sensitive to adjust successfully.

A small engine like this may not run smoothly below 2000RPM. Any sudden change in the load might cause it to stall, unless you add a bigger flywheel to your design.